API Response must display image
Everytime i click or serch the url it displays random codes
enter image description here
Im trying to achieve the result of image in postman or browser if i use get method for my url sample : https://localhost:7131/owner/trainee/photo/TEST/TEST.jpg It should directly display an image
This is my api code
[HttpGet("photo/{token}/{filename}")]
public async Task traineePicture()
{=Byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\lem\Pictures\Saved Pictures\nando-jpeg-quality-001.jpg");
return File(b, "image /jpg");
}

First Step you must write UseStaticFiles() in  Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}

After you can write
var imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
return File(imageBytes, "image/jpeg");

